# What to do when file output turns Chinese?

Tags: c#, .net, ascii

Suddenly, my output file decided to become Chinese. I tried to write some random ASCII characters to a file, but instead of writing ASCII, C# decided to write ancient Chinese letters instead. Is it trying to tell me something?

```
static void WriteToFile()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            int x = 0;
            x = rand.Next(0, 127);
            writer.Write((char)x);
        }
        writer.Close();
    }
```

[image]

Comment: static TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter("notepad");

Answer (score 2):

When you write a text file without a BOM, you leave it up to the program that reads the file to guess at the encoding that was used to convert text to the bytes in the file.  Notepad uses a heuristic if you don't pick the Encoding from its File + Open dialog.  Underlying winapi call is [IsTextUnicode()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318672%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

With random byte values, like you use, and way too many ASCII control characters present it isn't unlikely to pick `IS_TEXT_UNICODE_ASCII16` (aka utf-16).  Yes, that looks like Chinese, two bytes select the glyph.  Writing the BOM keeps you out of trouble, utf-8 being the sane choice.  And no control characters, most don't have a matching glyph.  Pick from the range 32..127.  Google "bush hid the facts" for an amusing story about an early version of IsTextUnicode() fumbling the guess.

Comment: Thanks for the deeper answer on this subject. Really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the issue is you are writing values that are not displayable, like the first 32 characters in ASCII. When writing them as [UTF-8 without a BOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtbhzte9.aspx) (which is the default in .NET for `StreamWriter`), you might end up with unexpected results.

This code yields the expected result:

```
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();

Random rand = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    int x = 0;
    x = rand.Next(32, 126);
    writer.Write((char)x);
}

writer.Close();

string s = writer.ToString();

File.WriteAllText(@"C:\temp\so2343.dat", s, Encoding.ASCII);
```

Also note the code change I made to `rand.Next` to only get the visible characters.

Answer (score 0):

You're writing raw bytes into the file and `Notepad` treats the resulting file as unicode.